# Gradle eclipseClasspath avoid adding Gradle Dependencies

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have a really special problem with Eclipse and Gradle.
I use the Gradle IDE within Eclipse.

The default implementation of Gradle sets up the classpath in a way, that it will work without the Gradle IDE Plugin.

Therefore it adds all resolved dependencies into the .classpath file.

But in my environment I now have the dependencies twice. Once directly (from the .classpath file) and another under "Gradle Dependencies"

http://imagebin.org/303448

It works fine with "Gradle Dependencies" only.

At http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html it shows a way to customize the eclipseClasspath task.

But I don't know what general "minusConfigurations" I can use to avoid adding Gradle dependencies to the .classpath file

Comment: Sounds like you both run `gradle eclipse` and import using the STS plugin.

Comment: No. I only use gradle eclipse and open the project in Eclipse. I never used something like a special import. Also after opening in Eclipse when running `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` I have the dependencies twice. The Gradle IDE, similar to Mavenm resolves Gradle Dependencies. That's really great. So only think that has to be done, is to hinder the eclipseClasspath task to also add the Gradle dependencies to the .classpath file. If the task is completely disabled, no .classpath is created... tried that, but without a .classpath Eclipse is not working properly.

Comment: When using the STS plugin, you should never run `gradle eclipse`. Instead, you should use "Import Gradle Project".

Comment: Okay I just tried it that way. Interesting, the wizzard suggest to run *cleanEclipse eclipse* before import. When doing so, it behaves as before, doubled dependencies. Explicitly deactivating **Run before** works nearly. Now there are only the Gradle Dependencies, but not the .classpath needs to be manually fixed. Gradle defaults to the **build** folder, Eclipse defaults to the **bin** folder. Therefore every build.gradle I use contains `eclipse.classpath.defaultOutputDir = file('build/classes')`. So it's again only a 90% solution. Either delete the doubled dependencies or change the buildpath

Comment: Gradle intentionally sets the Eclipse output dir to `bin`. Setting it to `build/classes` can cause troubles, as two (very different!) compilers are now writing to the same directory without being aware of each other. Of course you are free to reconfigure this to your liking.

Comment: No it doesn't. Just tried it, cause you told it. Removed my own defaultOutputDir. Imported the Gradle Project into Eclipse. A Build Folder is created. Also when running the build task, everything get's written into the build folder. Without using defaultOutputDir, I'll have to build folders. That does not make sense. The builds working fine, when only using build/classes

Comment: Nevertheless thank you, I'll stay with your suggestion and use "Import Gradle Project" for the future. But use the **Run Before** `cleanEclipse eclipse` and then manually delete the doubled classpath entries. Ideally somebody can tell me how to configure the task eclipseClasspath in my build.gradle that the double entries are not created. This was my initial question.

Comment: `tasks.eclipseClasspath.enabled = false`. Just because writing to `build/classes` doesn't cause problems for you right now doesn't mean it's a good default.

Comment: eclipseClasspath.enabled = false is not the solution as written above (second comment). It then won't create the .classpath file, so again so many things to do by hand. I search the Gradle GitHub to find the Gradle for the task eclipseClasspath, but without success. I don't know how it does what it does, so I have no idea how to **only avoid the add of the JAR files directly into the .classpath**. Gradle is so flexible can't believe that this is not possible.

Comment: The `eclipseClasspath` task isn't meant to be used together with the STS plugin. Configuration options such as `eclipse.classpath.defaultOutputDir` should be honored nevertheless (though maybe some of them aren't yet). The *run before* option is more of a workaround than anything else, and I expect it to go away in the future.

Comment: Okay, I understand, thank you. Can you give me an example about bad thinks that may happen when Eclipse is using build/classes and Gradle is also using it?